# Installing Eclipse on Linux - Screen for GtkWindow not set

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

I installed the 32 bit Linux version of [Eclipse for Java EE Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigosr1) on a Linux server and I'm having issues launching eclipse from the Linux machine. I've edited my **`eclipse.ini`** and added the `vm` Java path (see below):

**Exception:**

> (Eclipse:22632): Gtk-WARNING **: Screen for GtkWindow not set; you
>   must always set a screen for a GtkWindow before using the window

**eclipse.ini file:**

```
-startup
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.100.v20110505
-product
    org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
    openFile
-showsplash
    org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
    256m
--launcher.defaultAction
    openFile
-vm
    /opt/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Comment: you have a graphical environment on a linux server?! What window manager do you use?

Comment: The Linux machine is a remote machine that I connect to from my local Mac machine via ssh. Isn't there a way to execute eclipse and have it open up on my local machine?

Comment: I've tried adding export DISPLAY=121.71.229.115:0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to have an X Server running on the remote machine. You also need to have permissions to forward X and use it in your SSH connection. See this [article](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/ch09_03.htm) for example, or search for forwarding X11 via SSH for your Linux distribution

Answer (score 1):

First you need X11 installed on your Mac.
Then try something simpler, like

```
$ ssh -X server xclock
```

If xclock is displayed, you can try

```
$ ssh -X server eclipse
```