# Can not run eclipse on command line on Ubuntu server

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-cdt

When I try to build eclipse-cdt projects in eclipse on Ubuntu Server I always get the error below.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-03-24 12:26:18.678
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [gtk_init_check() failed]
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4387)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Display.java:914)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:900)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:716)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

There is no GUI installed on the server and I think it is the reason. Anyway I can not make it work.
Is there a way to build eclipse cdt projects on Ubuntu Server without a GUI?

Comment: Are you seriously asking how to run a GUI application on a machine without a GUI? I guess you might look into the concept of **build systems** (like ant, maven, make, sbt, ...) 
If your project should be build on the command line, then use a build system that works on the command line.

Comment: Maybe you should tell us the whole picture, I assume you don't try to start eclipse to take a look at its main window

Comment: If you're connecting remotely to that server, perhaps consider installing a X Server on your local machine and directing Eclipse to it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072693/installing-eclipse-on-linux-screen-for-gtkwindow-not-set

Comment: I want to build my eclipse projects on ubuntu server for release packages creation.  Of course the projects developed on machines with GUI. But on this server there is not a gui and I think there should be a way of running eclipse to just build the project without installing a GUI. And I am really serious.

Comment: CDT uses make files, just use those from the command line.